# C# send a json object on url to php

Tags: c#, json

I have a problem: I want to send a json object on url.

I used newtonsoft.com to convert dataset to json, but when I execute the code it opens me several in each onlet part of file json

```
String xmlString = DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(myDataSet2).ToString(); 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"http://127.0.0.1/test/page1.php?appid=" + xmlString);

public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataSet table)
{
    string JSONString = string.Empty;
    JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
    return JSONString;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use HttpClient instead?

Comment: "it opens me several in each onlet part of file json" Really not sure what that is supposed to mean. Can you try and clarify?

Comment: you're not supposed to send json data in the url if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: when I execute the code in google chrome several tab opens in each tab a part of json file

Comment: The above code is dodgy. You don't need to run a process for the default browser to do the request, use C# to make a request, use .Net Framework classes.